# s() in mgcv doesn't work when VGAM package loaded

Tags: r, mgcv, vgam

This

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) 
gam(y ~ s(x))
## Family: gaussian 
## Link function: identity 

## Formula:
## y ~ s(x)

## Estimated degrees of freedom:
## 1  total = 2 

## GCV score: 0.8116283
```

breaks down, when `VGAM` package is loaded:

```
library(VGAM)
gam(y ~ s(x))
##Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Both implement `s()` function, but this shouldn't happen right? Is this an error in `mgcv` or `VGAM` package?

Comment: Where does the vglm package come from? Its not on CRAN.

Comment: I presume you mean the `VGAM` package (which has a function `vglm`) and demonstrates this problem.

Comment: It's 'user error'. You are the one who ignored the warning message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mgcv:gam` calls `mgcv:interpret.gam` which is where the fail is.

`interpret.gam` seems to parse the formula for special functions, including 's', and then evaluates `s(x)` in the environment of the formula. Which means it will find whatever the current 's' is from the caller. Which could be something that returns something that `gam` doesn't like.

You can't fix it like this:

```
> gam(y ~ mgcv::s(x))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ mgcv::s(x), drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'mgcv::s(x)'
> gam(y ~ mgcv:::s(x))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ mgcv:::s(x), drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'mgcv:::s(x)'
```

But you can like this:

```
> s=mgcv:::s
> gam(y ~ s(x))

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
1  total = 2 

GCV score: 0.9486058
```

So its not an error in either package. You asked for a gam with `s(x)`, and happened to have currently defined `s(x)` to be incompatible with that `gam` needs. You can't just plug any old function in there.

Comment: Thx, nice answer! I concede this is not an error, but shouldn't this be more robust? At least it could be checked in the environment of the formula if(s != mgcv:::s), resulting in a warning, otherwise there will always be an error when both packages are loaded and it can be hard to catch...

Comment: So exactly what charges are you going to lodge with the Package Police? If mgcv is loaded first and then VGAM, is mgcv's author responsible for generating a warning, or is it VGAM's author? You were warned if mgcv::s or mgcv::interpret.gam were masked at the time of loading the second package. You just chose to ignore the warning.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that mgcv is trying to let you be flexible at the cost of allowing you to break stuff, whilst itself breaking the principle of least surprise. If you do: `f=mgcv:::s ; gam(y~f(x))` it breaks, even though `f` is `s`, because `gam()` actually looks for an `s` character. The `s` function is very very special to `gam()`. I'd suggest to the `mgcv` guys that they make `s` a function with a class and check that class in `gam()`.